# Debian package rules file: debhelper doesn't seem to be called as expected

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I want to install a systemd unit using debhelper and dh_installsystemd.

My control file:

```
Package: prometheus-wireguard-exporter
Version: 3.6.3-###CI_JOB_ID###
Maintainer: Ronny Forberger
Architecture: amd64
Build-Depends: debhelper, dh-systemd (>= 1.5)
Description: Prometheus Wireguard Exporter
```

My rules file:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
export DH_VERBOSE = 1

%:
        dh $@ --with systemd

override_dh_installsystemd:
        dh_installsystemd --name=prometheus-wireguard-exporter
```

Directory tree:

```
prometheus_wireguard_exporter_amd64
├── debian -> DEBIAN
└── DEBIAN
    ├── control
    ├── postinst
    ├── prometheus-wireguard-exporter.prometheus-wireguard-exporter.service -> prometheus-wireguard-exporter.service
    ├── prometheus-wireguard-exporter.service
    └── rules

2 directories, 5 files
```

my postinst script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# source debconf library
. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

# dh_installdeb will replace this with shell code automatically
# generated by other debhelper scripts.

#DEBHELPER#

db_stop

exit 0
```

I build the package with `dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group -v prometheus_wireguard_exporter_amd64`

The postinst script runs, but seems not to call debhelper.

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to benefit from `debhelper`, you need to build from a source package, instead of building a binary package directly:

- drop the `debian` symlink to `DEBIAN`
- rename `DEBIAN` to `debian`
- rename `prometheus_wireguard_exporter_amd64` to `prometheus-wireguard-exporter`
- add a `debian/changelog` file (`dch --create`)
- build your package using `dpkg-buildpackage` (`dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc`)